# ASP.NET + jQuery AJAX - getting 500 server error

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I want to call an ASP.NET function from jQuery by AJAX with response.

I have file Controll.aspx where is included javascript code. Next I have /Services/ControllService.asmx, where is the function, which I want call from js.

js code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btn_start').on('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Services/ControllService.asmx/Start",
            data: {},
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert("Error:" + err.toString());
            }
        });

    });
});
```

But I still getting the error 500.

```
POST http://localhost:56000/Services/ControllService.asmx/Start 500 (Internal Server Error)
k.cors.a.crossDomain.send
n.extend.ajax
```

Do you have any hints, what do I need to set e.g. in Web.config?

Many thanks.

Comment: Could you post your C# method `Start`

Comment: You should catch the exception in your code and this will give you more information. Or you can analyse the response body from the network inspector where you will see the error page that is generated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED:**

1 - I have defined `Start` function in ControllService.asmx.cs as static.

2 - I have badly configured data. It has to be named by the same way e.g. "sth".

In javascript it should be:

```
...
url: "Services/ControllService.asmx/Start",
data: JSON.stringify({ sth: "hahaha" }),
dataType: "json",
...
```

and in ControllService.asmx.cs -> method Start

```
public string Start(string sth){}
```

Many, many thanks for your hints.